# Ionic3 iOS Icons are missing on app resume clicking on push notification

Tags: ios, ionic3, icons

In ionic3 iOS, when opening app able to see all icons and images from assets folder.
When app is in background and clicking on push notification, app opens but all icons and images from assets folder goes missing.

In below image all the squares or rectangles you can see are missing icons and images after opening app using push notification.

This issue occurs only in iOS. how to fix it?

[SCREENSHOT OF MISSING ICONS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sRX1S.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

Did you specify a different path when you resume your app? Also, you need to specify the path to the www-folder, the one not included in your git, not to your src folder. When you build your app, ionic will create a copy of your images on your www-folder so you can work with them locally and you won't touch yor source.

Comment: I have developed own tabs alike component, clicking on any tab icon, it sets the relevant page as root page. So probably on resume, yes the root path can be vary. Regarding www-folder - I can say, initially the icons and images works fine, even when app is killed and opens again, it works fine. Issue occurs only when app come to foreground on clicking on push notification. also Its working fine in android in all of above cases. issue comes only in iOS

Comment: Yes, I had the same issue, my guess is that the path is not relative because it's what solved mine. Can you post your path string?

Comment: Here is my array of tabs: 
[{id:0, tabID:1, "root":ChatPage, tabTitle:"Chat"},
          {id:1, tabID:2, "root":GroupPage, tabTitle:"Groups"},
          {id:2, tabID:3, "root":SMSPage, tabTitle:"SMS"},
          {id:3, tabID:4, "root":User_PhoneSectionPage, tabTitle:"Phone”},…];

Comment: While loading app, I pickup one of active tab from the list and push it as root tab using below code

let nav = this.app.getRootNav();
nav.setRoot(this.activetabs[0].root);

Comment: ok. What is your string path? is it something like this: `"assets/img/example.png"` ?

Comment: yes src="assets/imgs/logo-axion.png" and icons as <ion-icon name="menu"></ion-icon>

Comment: did you sanitize your resources? `this.sanitize.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(window.Ionic.WebView.convertFileSrc(path))`  where path is assets/imgs/logo-axion.png

Comment: no I use it this way <img src="assets/imgs/logo-axion.png"> which works perfectly fine in iOS as well while loading app first time. it disappears only when app in background and clicking on notification.

Comment: do you get any type of error or exception?

Comment: no nothing, clicking on notification app works fine without icons and images

Comment: one more input is, I am also using font-awesome icons at some places. can that create this problem?

Comment: no, I would say it's related to the resume. What are you using for the push notifications? Firebase?

Comment: using one signal for push notification

Comment: do you have any resources related to push notifications like the icon of your app when the notification shows up? If yes are those resources at the same path of your other icons, or in a different folder?

Comment: in iOS, app icon comes default as notification icon. in android notification icons in android/app/src/main/res/

Comment: Ok. Try to implement a script when you fire the onResume event on ios and set the path directory back to assets/imgs/logo-axion.png